# Meaning of "mapped as" in context

Tags: british-english

Recently I come across the following sentence:

> The “Ship Date” is mapped as the “Current Date” for the order.

It was part of my task as a software developer, the context is that I need to set values from one cell to another in a table.

I interpreted it as: set "Ship date" with the value of "current date".

But turned out that the native speaker who wrote this meant: set "current date" with the value of "Ship date".

For me it looks strange, can you explain in terms of grammar how it works?

Comment: No - the cited text doesn't *exactly* mean *set "Ship date" with the value of "current date"*, because that would imply a "one-time" change in the value stored in a computer programming variable called "Ship date". But ***mapping*** one variable to another means something very specific in programming. Specifically, it means that *whenever* the code attempts to retrieve the value of the variable called "Shit date", what it actually gets is whatever value is *currently* held in some variable or function return value called "current date". This is domain-specific ***programming terminology***.

Comment: Syntactically, *X is mapped **as** Y* is probably less common than *X is mapped **to** Y*, but they'd both mean the same anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, don't go too far into programming. Let's say we talking about excel spreadsheet. So "map a as b" means a=b or b=a?

Comment: You can't avoid going into programming here - the usage you're asking about ***is a domain-specific programming usage***. Even if your *exact* context is a spreadsheet rather than a program written in C++ or whatever, the usage must be interpreted as it applies in the "original" context. Excel certainly supports a "programming" lasnguage, but I don't know the internal details of how it might "map" the contents of one cell to another. It's always feasible your cited usage is in fact a ***misuse***, but to follow that up we'd need more context (and someone who knows more about Excel than me! :)

Comment: Approximately, I'd say that *Map X as Y* means *set the address pointer of variable X to point to the same data as variable Y, so that any change or retrieval of **either** variable affects or access the other variable "as well"* (the two separate variables effectively become a *single* variable with two different names).

Comment: You could say "the ship date is entered (into the form) as the current date for the order" or similar verbs instead of *entered*, and *as* would make more sense there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for the detailed answer. If you need more programming context: we have a pipeline where the structure pushed through is an order. At a different stages, we perform different calculations on the order.  Here we assign the value(not a pointer) of one attribute to another attribute of an order on a given condition.  It boils down to `if order.x="abc" then order. y=x `

Comment: So far as ***use of English*** is concerned, your cited example meets the (subscription only) full Oxford English Dictionary definition 3d for the transitive verb: [Computing] *To associate (an item of data) with a specified location in memory; to associate (a memory location) with a data item. With **into, on to, to**.* Precisely how that definition covers the actual process in the context of a spreadsheet is beyond the scope of this site. I'm sure there will be some other "programming" sub-site within Stack Exchange that can address the details, ***if the cited usage is in fact "valid"***.

Comment: If you haven't realised it yet, your comment question about whether *Map X to Y* means *Let X = Y* OR *Let Y = X* is meaningless. Once X is mapped to Y, X and Y become effectively "the same variable", so changing the value of either inherently changes the value of the other ***at the same time***.

Comment: So far it clarified for me this situation, thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: Is the person who wrote the sentence a programmer or other technical expert? It looks to me like the sort of thing that a person with a poor grasp of the concepts might write thinking they were being technical. Just because someone is a native speaker doesn't mean that they understand or use technical language correctly. Setting the shipping date to the system date makes sense but setting "today" to the date the order was shipped does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The “Ship Date” is mapped as the “Current Date” for the order.*

= The “Ship Date” is mapped [by you] as [if it were] the “Current Date” for the order.

= you should map the "Ship Date" [as if it were] the “Current Date” for the order.

The implication is then that "Ship Date" = "Current Date"

Comment: So it means I understand it correctly, is there any way that it could be perceived as "current date"="ship date" ?

Comment: I think it is possible. In the instruction *"The “Ship Date” is mapped as the “Current Date”", as I understand it, **to map** = "to set with reference to a function", and the action of the verb (set) will be on "Ship Date". Thus *"The “Ship Date” is set with reference to the function of “Current Date”. This implies that "Current Date" is the important function. That said, I have no idea why the writer did not say "The function "Current Date" should be used for "Ship Date.""